# Has Asus fixed the heat sink problem with the Strix 980ti

Tags: gaming, graphics-cards, game-development

I just built a new gaming computer.  It's a skylake build with the i7 6700k, Asus Maximus viii hero, and some g.skill ram (32gb).

I'm about to buy a new video card, and I've been looking over the options for a couple of weeks.

I've decided that I want to spend between $650 and $700 and get a 980ti.

This turned out to be a pretty large point of contention in the forums I've been looking through, so I figured I'd check here.

In the benchmarks I've looked at, I've seen pretty good comparisons [here](http://techreport.com/review/28685/geforce-gtx-980-ti-cards-compared/5) and [here](http://techreport.com/review/28685/geforce-gtx-980-ti-cards-compared/5) between the
**Asus Strix OC**, **Gigabyte G1 Gaming**, **MSI Gaming 6G**, **EVGA SC**.

I've narrowed it down to the **Asus Strix OC**, **MSI Gaming 6G**, and adding in the **Gigabyte Xtreme**.

Based on different reviews, I decided on the Strix at one point, but I keep seeing people complain about their heatsink not touching their processor.

I've had a couple of bad experiences with Gigabyte products, so the xtreme makes me a little nervous.

And the MSI Gaming clashes terribly with my mobo/case (also, it's the least powerful of the three cards chosen).

Any advice on how to decide?  I know they are all amazing cards, and there probably isn't a wrong choice, but this is my first REAL gaming rig, and don't want any regrets.  I'm loving the cpu/mobo so far, and really want to stay happy.  Feel free to throw any other card in that price range at me, and I'll look into it.  Any advice is welcome.

---

### **Side Note**

This really shouldn't be a side note, but I'll be using this computer for general use.  I will do some amount of game development on it, but not much, and some general programming, but the video card is obviously so I can get max settings on any game I want for a while.

---

### **Edit1**

In order to make this less opinion based, I've changed the actual question. I know I want the Strix because of how fantastic its performance in benchmarks is, but I'm worried about the past problems with their heatsink.  Does anyone know if Asus has fixed the problem with the Strix cards?  If no one knows, I think I'd rather go with the Gigabyte Xtreme, to avoid having to send a card back.

Comment: This question is currently primarily opinion based, as you haven't really specified what your requirements are, just the model of the card you want. I'd suggest you add what case you're using, what kind of noise levels you're hoping for, whether you'll be overclocking, what colour theme you're hoping for, and any other nice to have features.